# Why am I getting Error: need a single repository as argument for sudo add-apt-repository ppa: paolorotolo / android-studio

Tags: apt, android, ppa, repository

I am executing the following command as per the instructions in the [link](http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/132-mobile/779326-mobile-development-how-to-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu-version-1404).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa: paolorotolo / android-studio
```

I am getting the error -

```
Error: need a single repository as argument.
```

I am running 64 bit Ubuntu 14.0

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have spaces in the repository name. It should be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
```